# issues when using caffe (create_imagenet.sh) to convert my jpg to lmdb

Tags: linux, machine-learning, caffe, lmdb

I want to do fine-tuning to train my jpg. Guided by many documents, I mainly modified the path of data, txt and tool in create_imagenet.sh, as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# This script converts the mnist data into lmdb/leveldb format,
# depending on the value assigned to $BACKEND.
set -e

EXAMPLE=/home/sun/Documents/python/fine-tuning/Oxford102/data/test
DATA_TEST=/home/sun/Documents/python/fine-tuning/Oxford102/data/test/test/
DATA_TRAIN=/home/sun/Documents/python/fine-tuning/Oxford102/data/test/train/
NOTI=/home/sun/Documents/python/fine-tuning/Oxford102/data/test
BUILD=/home/sun/Documents/caffe/build/tools

#BACKEND="lmdb"

# Set RESIZE=true to resize the images to 256x256. Leave as false if images have  
# already been resized using another tool.  
RESIZE=true
if $RESIZE; then  
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=256  
  RESIZE_WIDTH=256  
else  
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=0  
  RESIZE_WIDTH=0  
fi  


if [ ! -d "$DATA_TRAIN" ]; then  
  echo "Error: TRAIN_DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory: $DATA_TRAIN"  
  echo "Set the TRAIN_DATA_ROOT variable in create_imagenet.sh to the path" \  
       "where the ImageNet training data is stored."  
  exit 1  
fi  

if [ ! -d "$DATA_TEST" ]; then  
  echo "Error: TRAIN_DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory: $DATA_TEST"  
  echo "Set the TRAIN_DATA_ROOT variable in create_imagenet.sh to the path" \  
       "where the ImageNet training data is stored."  
  exit 1  
fi  

echo "Creating train lmdb..."
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $BUILD/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \ 
    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
    --shuffle \
    $DATA_TRAIN \  
    $NOTI/info_train.txt \  
    $EXAMPLE/img_train_lmdb  

echo "Creating test lmdb..."
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $BUILD/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \ 
    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
    --shuffle \
    $DATA_TEST \  
    $NOTI/info_test.txt \  
    $EXAMPLE/img_test_lmdb

echo "Done."
```

Then I run 'sudo sh create_oxford.sh' in terminal, while got nothing.

[running result in shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9zNI.png)

Besides, my document structure is as following:

in /home/sun/Documents/python/fine-tuning/Oxford102/data/test, I put info_test.txt, info_train.txt, test(jpg for test) and train(jpg for train). In the txt, the information is like 'image_0001.jpg 0'.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** I successfully ran the code.

**2)** I am getting the usage and nothing, when command line arguments are not passing correctly.

**3)** You can debug your shell script using: set -vx
It will show actual arguements as follows:

+/home/u5652/.conda/envs/riCffAlex3.6/bin/convert_imageset **--resize_height=256 --resize_width=256**

convert_imageset: Convert a set of images to the leveldb/lmdb
format used as input for Caffe.
Usage:
    convert_imageset [FLAGS] ROOTFOLDER/ LISTFILE DB_NAME
.....................

As per caffe/tools/convert_imageset.cpp:

```
if (argc < 4) {
    gflags::ShowUsageWithFlagsRestrict(argv[0], "tools/convert_imageset");
    return 1;
  }
```

minimum arguements should be 4, else it will show usage.
**You must have been getting usage and nothing because of incorrect arguments.**

**4)** I ran the following code and am successful in creating lmdb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -vx
EXAMPLE=examples/imagenet/test
DATA=data/ilsvrc12/test
TOOLS=~/.conda/envs/riCffAlex3.6/bin
TRAIN_DATA_ROOT=~/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/test/train/
VAL_DATA_ROOT=~/caffe/data/ilsvrc12/test/test/

RESIZE=true
if $RESIZE; then
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=256
  RESIZE_WIDTH=256
else
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=0
  RESIZE_WIDTH=0
fi

if [ ! -d "$TRAIN_DATA_ROOT" ]; then
  echo "Error: TRAIN_DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory: $TRAIN_DATA_ROOT"
  echo "Set the TRAIN_DATA_ROOT variable in create_imagenet.sh to the path" \
       "where the ImageNet training data is stored."
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$VAL_DATA_ROOT" ]; then
  echo "Error: VAL_DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory: $VAL_DATA_ROOT"
  echo "Set the VAL_DATA_ROOT variable in create_imagenet.sh to the path" \
       "where the ImageNet validation data is stored."
  exit 1
fi

echo "Creating train lmdb..."

GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \
    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
    --shuffle \
    $TRAIN_DATA_ROOT \
    $DATA/train.txt \
    $EXAMPLE/train_lmdb

echo "Creating test lmdb..."

GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \
    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
    --shuffle \
    $VAL_DATA_ROOT \
    $DATA/val.txt \
    $EXAMPLE/test_lmdb

echo "Done."
```

**5)** I put details in same format as you put in .txt files. I put: TestJpg.jpg 0

**NOTE:** Image should have same name and extension as you are putting in .txt

Try the way. Your error should be resolved.

Thanks

Comment: thank you very much! I've solved the problem by cancel the '\' and put all params in one line. It seems that the \ doesn't act as connection commands on my machine.